# Как удалить элемент после их создания при повторном клике?

Tags: jquery

Написал условие, текст добавляется в нужный родитель, а вот при повторном нажатии на элемент, не удаляется:

Вот пример кода:

```js
$(".item").click(function() {
  
  var text = $(this).text();

  $(this).toggleClass("active");

  $("#memory").append("&nbsp;<span>" + text + "</span>,");

  if ($(".item.active").length > 0) {
    $(".double-dots").show();
  } else {
    $(".double-dots").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-select">
  <div id="memory">
    <span>Встроенная память</span>
    <span class="double-dots" style="display: none">:</span>
  </div>

  <ul class="filter">
    <li class="item">256 GB</li>
    <li class="item">128 GB</li>
    <li class="item">64 GB</li>
    <li class="item">16 GB</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".item").click(function() {
  
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  var text = "&nbsp;<span>" + $(this).text() + "</span>,";

  $("#memory").html($("#memory").html().replace(text, ""));
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $("#memory").append(text);
  }
  
  if ($(".item.active").length) {
    $(".double-dots").show();
  } else {
    $(".double-dots").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-select">
  <div id="memory">
    <span>Встроенная память</span>
    <span class="double-dots" style="display: none">:</span>
  </div>

  <ul class="filter">
    <li class="item">256 GB</li>
    <li class="item">128 GB</li>
    <li class="item">64 GB</li>
    <li class="item">16 GB</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```